# Compiler error for Haskell program not understood

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, parse-error

I'm working on a large Haskell program, so I'm only including the code that seems relevant here to make the problem clearer.  Please comment if I should include more.

When I compile, I get only one error message: "parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)"

Here is some code with no errors (printStmt) and a very similar section (VarDeclStmt) with the error directed at the line reading, "expr >>= \s ->".  I don't see why one would be fine and the other would cause a problem.  In what way are they different?

```
printStmt = 
            keyword "print" >>
            expr >>= \e ->
            symbol ";" >>
            return (Print e)

varDeclStmt = do
              keyword "var" >>
              expr >>= \s -> --ERROR
              symbol "=" >>
              expr >>= \e ->
              return (VarDecl s e)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an indentation issue. The block

```
varDeclStmt = do
              keyword "var" >>
              expr >>= \s -> --ERROR
              symbol "=" >>
              expr >>= \e ->
              return (VarDecl s e)
```

parses as

```
varDeclStmt = do
              { keyword "var" >>
              ; expr >>= \s -> --ERROR
              ; symbol "=" >>
              ; expr >>= \e ->
              ; return (VarDecl s e) 
              }
```

which is nonsense, since the first entry `keyword "var" >>` is not valid.

Note that indenting the whole block further (or less) does not change how it is parsed.

The easiest fix is to remove `do` completely, so that the text below that is not parsed as a block, hence it is not split into separate entries, but parsed as if it were on a single line.

Otherwise, you can switch to proper `do` notation

```
varDeclStmt = do
              keyword "var"
              s <- expr
              symbol "="
              e <- expr
              return (VarDecl s e)
```

or (worst solution), make the `do` block a single-entry one, making the block indented more than the first line, as follos

```
varDeclStmt = do
              keyword "var" >>
                expr >>= \s ->
                symbol "=" >>
                expr >>= \e ->
                return (VarDecl s e)
```

The above solution is silly, though, since the purpose of `do` is splitting the block into entries, and the indentation is made so that there is only one entry. So, we use two things to counteract each other.

Answer (score 2):

The indentation error has to do with the `do` block. Try indenting after the `do`. Something like:

```
varDeclStmt = do
                keyword "var" >>
                expr >>= \s -> 
                symbol "=" >>
                expr >>= \e ->
                return (VarDecl s e)
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that the `do` keyword is unnecessary here, since do-notation is not really being used.

Comment: This won't work: the indentation rule checks the indentation of the first word after `do` against the indentation of the next lines. The indentation of `do` wrt the block is not taken into consideration. Still, removing `do` is the easiest fix here.